# A react component is not rendered even after calling it through ReactDOM.render( ) method

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

*I am creating a simple voting_app in React while learning from a book.I have an index.html file,all the css files are in respective folders,app1.js file,I've put all those files below.*

*The issue is when i call a component app1.js through ReactDOM.render() method ,it doesn't show in the browser.*

**app-1.js**

```
class ProductList extends React.Component {
render() {
return (<div className='ui unstackable items'>
Hello, friend! I am a basic React component.
</div>);
}}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**Index.html**

```
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project One</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./semantic.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>
    <script src="vendor/babel-standalone.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
    Your first React Web Application14
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main ui text container">
    <h1 class="ui dividing centered header">Popular Products</h1>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </div>

    <script  type="text/babel"
    data-plugins="transform-class-properties"
    src="./js/app.js"></script><!--Delete the script tag below to get started.-->
    <script src="vendor/react.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: following is my project directory]

[image: this is my output]

[image: This is what I expect it to show]

Comment: do you have an error in the console ? Anyway, I think you must include the vendor rect script before your own script

Comment: As you said I addded vendor script before my script ,but it didn't work.

Comment: Then something else is going on because your code does work.

Comment: maybe a problem with babel transpilation, try to add `data-presets="es2015,react"` to your script tag, and remove the  second declaraction of `vendor/react.js`

Comment: does it show the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might comes from the babel transpilation, try to use the following script declaration (also note that your script file is named `app-1.js` not `app.js`)

```
<script type="text/babel" src="js/app-1.js" data-presets="es2015,react"></script>
```

As you can see below, your component is displayed correctly

```js
class ProductList extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className='ui unstackable items'>
         Hello, friend! I am a basic React component.
        </div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductList />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved .I think I didn't pay much attention to the name of the component there.lol